# Cannot get an output Python Classes and Functions code

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, class

I recently submitted this homework but couldn't get the code of either problems working. I would love to know what I could have done to make sure I do it right the next time.

**Question 1** (5 points) 
Create a base/parent class called 'InterestCalculator'.
Create a child class called 'CICalculator'.
The 'CICalculator' class will have only one parent, the 'InterestCalculator'. Create a child class called 'SICalculator'. The 'SI' class will have only one parent, the 'InterestCalculator'.
The parent class needs to have an **init** method, that will initialize
all the values needed for calculating and storing interest.

The child class 'CICalculator' and 'SICalculator'
must implement 'calcfinalval' method that will calculate the final value
for each case.

Compound Interest is given by A = p*(1+(r/(n*100)))^(n*t) where p is the principal amount, r is the rate of interest and t is time in years and n is the number of times interest is compounded annually and A is the total amount after t years.
Assume n = 2.

Simple Interest is given by A = p(1+(r*t/100) where p is the principal,
r is the rate of interest and t is time in years and A is the total amount
after t years.

Once all classes have been defined, the call to calculate and print the
final value must follow the code below.

```
    c = CICalculator(2,0.1,1000)
    c.calcfinalval()
    print c.finalval

    s = SICalculator(2,0.1,1000)
    s.calcfinalval()
    print s.finalval
```

**# solution 1**

```
class InterestCalculator:
   def __init__(self, A, p, r, y, t):
      self.A = A
      self.p = p
      self.r = r
      self.y = y
      self.t = t

  def calcfinalval(self):
    return "Interest Rates"


class CICalculator(InterestCalculator):
  def __init__(self, A, p, r, y, t):
  self.A = self.p*(1+(self.r/(self.t*100)))^(self.t*self.y)

class SICalculator(InterestCalculator):
  def __init__(self, A, p, r, y):
  self.A = self.p(1+(self.r*self.y/100)

c = CICalculator(2,0.1,1000)
c.calcfinalval()
print c.finalval

s = SICalculator(2,0.1,1000)
s.calcfinalval()
print s.finalval
```

**Question 2** (5 points) 
A queue follows FIFO (first-in, first-out). FIFO is the case where the
first element added is the first element  that can be retrieved. Consider
a list with values [1,2,3]. Create a class called MyQueue that will have
two methods: queueadd and queueretrieve to add and retrieve elements
from the list in FIFO order respectively. After each function call,
print the contents of the list. Add 7 to the queue and then follow the
FIFO rules to retrieve an element.

Your call to the class will be as follows
       a = [1,2,3]
       q = MyQueue(a)
       q.queueadd(7)
       q.queueretrieve()

The output on the screen should similar to

```
    1 2 3 7
    2 3 7
    3 7 
    7
```

**# solution 2**

```
 class MyQueue: 

    def __init__(self):
    self.in_stack = []
    self.out_stack = []

    def queueadd(self, obj):
    self.in_stack.append(obj)

    def queueretrieve(self):
    if not self.out_stack:
        while self.in_stack:
            self.out_stack.append(self.in_stack.pop())
    return self.out_stack.pop()

    a = [1,2,3]
    q = MyQueue(a)
    q.queueadd(7)
    q.queueretrieve()
```

Comment: Did you test your code? There are a lot of errors. I would suspect that a moderator will soon come along and close your question as too broad. I would recommend testing the code, reading the error messages, modifying it accordingly, and then--if you still can't figure it out--posting 1 *specific* question (i.e., not the full homework question)

Answer (score -1):

A way to implement Q1 in a similar way that you have implemented in Solution 1 is :

```
class InterestCalculator:
    def __init__(self,p, r, y, t):
        self.p = p
        self.r = r
        self.y = y
        self.t = t

class CICalculator(InterestCalculator):
    def __init__(self,InterestCalculator):
        self.p=InterestCalculator.p
        self.r=InterestCalculator.r
        self.y=InterestCalculator.y
        self.t=InterestCalculator.t
    def calcfinalval(self):
        val = self.p*(1+(self.r/(self.t*100.0)))**(self.t*self.y)
        return val

class SICalculator(InterestCalculator):
    def __init__(self,InterestCalculator):
        self.p=InterestCalculator.p
        self.r=InterestCalculator.r
        self.y=InterestCalculator.y
    def calcfinalval(self):
        val = self.p*(1+(self.r*self.y/100.0))
        return val

#Initialize an interestcalculator object
IC = InterestCalculator(1000,1,10,4)

#Create a CICalculator object
CI = CICalculator(IC)
print CI.calcfinalval()

SI = SICalculator(IC)
print SI.calcfinalval()
```

However, there are a lot of intricacies that I have changed in this code and I would suggest sitting down with someone who knows this stuff if you are serious about learning python.